# Replacing "that" with a present participle

Tags: relative-clauses, present-participles

Which makes more sense, or is more correct?

> one of the three fountains **standing** in the center of the garden

Or

> one of the three fountains **that stand** in the center of the garden.

I am trying to understand which is the more correct way to express phrases such as the above.

Comment: Are you familiar with the idiom [*six of one, half dozen of the other*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/six_of_one,_half_a_dozen_of_the_other)? I believe it applies here.

Comment: @Frank Allen As J.R. says, take your choice!

Comment: Same meaning but different syntax.

Answer (score 1):

> [1] *one of the three fountains [that stand in the center of the garden][*
>
> [2] *one of the three fountains [standing in the center of the garden]*

They both make perfect sense and neither is more 'correct' than the other.

Syntactically the main difference is that in [1] the bracketed element is a relative clause modifying "fountains", while in [2] it is a gerund-participial clause with the same function.

Semantically, there's no real difference between the two, so it all boils down to a matter of personal choice.